# calculator for binary number system

Tags: c#, binary, calculator

Can someone write me a calculator that takes two binary numbers and sums them up also multiplies them in C# (windows forms application), please?
i tried this one but it's not working

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    string[] array = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };              
    label1.Text = GetNumberFormBinary(array);     
}

private string GetNumberFormBinary(string[] array)     
{       
    string result = "";      
    int _base = 2;       
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)      
    {         
        int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(array[i], _base);         
        result += intValue.ToString();      
    }
 
    return result;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can *query* `array` and the result with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static string GetNumberFormBinary(string[] array) => array
  .Sum(item => Convert.ToInt32(item, 2))
  .ToString();
```